# How to switch on error messages in mathematica 10?

Tags: warning-messages

I have mathematica 10 and 8 on different computers. Version 8 always shows me the error message about what goes wrong while I don't see any error message in version 10. I find it quite inconvenient as it take much time to figure out the problem. How to switch on error messages in version 10 ?

I remember that version 10 did show the warning messages, but somebody calculated something using my mathematica and all error messages were gone after that.

Comment: Does executing `On[]` help?

Comment: yes, it turns on some message if I know what kind of messages it is. Do I have to turn them on 1 by 1?

Comment: You can try going to the menu bar Edit ▶ Preferences... and click "Reset to Defaults" under the Messages tab.

Comment: I solved it and thank you very much.

Comment: After your code add `// Quiet`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to check is what message options are set under Global Preferences in the Option Inspector. In particular, "KernelMessageAction" should be set to "PrintToNotebook". See window capture below.

[image: inspector]